# Sql Select query on select query result

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am trying to (select)query inside the previous (select)query from same table.

I've tried this below;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.strprcReturnEmpDetails(@EmpID VARCHAR(25))
AS
     SELECT [Name],
            Role,
            Email,
            Department,
            ReportingAuthority,
            DomainID,
            ReportsTo,
     (
         SELECT DISTINCT
                EmpID
         FROM Login
         WHERE [Name] = ReportsTo
     ) AS approverEmpid
     FROM Login
     WHERE EmpID = 288;
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     RETURN;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: (1) This query is not MySQL syntax (check your database and tag correctly).  (2) There are numerous syntax errors, regardless of database.
  (3) Provide sample data and desired results.  (4) I, for one, have no idea what your query is trying to do.

Comment: That code doesn't look like MySQL. (Perhaps the sql-server tag should be used instead?()

Comment: I guess your going to get an error along the lines of the subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just miss the aliases in the subquery to make it work. Your subquery returns more than one value, you need to make it a dependent subquery as follows:

```
SELECT [Name], Role, Email, Department, ReportingAuthority,DomainID,ReportsTo,
  ( 
    select distinct EmpID 
    from Login l2
    where l2.Name = l1.ReportsTo
  ) as approverEmpid 
FROM Login l1
WHERE EmpID=288
```

This should work if `Name` in `Login` table is unique.

Comment: Wow you nailed my ignorance Radim,Thanks

Comment: @user3926897 I'm glad it helped :)